# Add decimals to PHP output in script

Tags: php

I have a very simple PHP script in which I can add expenses, however when displaying, the decimal points are missing.

Here my current code to retrieve the data from the database:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered mg-b-0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>S.NO</th>
              <th>Expense Item</th>
              <th>Expense Cost</th>
              <th>Expense Date</th>
              <th>Cateogry</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <?php
            $userid=$_SESSION['detsuid'];
            $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblexpense where UserId='$userid'");
            $cnt=1;
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
            ?>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $cnt;?></td>

              <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseItem'];?></td>
              <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseCost'];?></td>
              <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseDate'];?></td>
              <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseCat'];?></td>
              <td><a href="manage-expense.php?delid=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">Delete</a>
            </tr>
            <?php $cnt=$cnt+1;}?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

and here my current output:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered mg-b-0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S.NO</th>
          <th>Expense Item</th>
          <th>Expense Cost</th>
          <th>Expense Date</th>
          <th>Cateogry</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>          
          <td>Test Expense</td>
          <td>4357745</td>
          <td>2020-02-13</td>
          <td>Office Supplies</td>
          <td><a href="manage-expense.php?delid=59">Delete</a>
        </td></tr>        
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

How can I change my code to display the price values correctly with decimals? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have a look at the function `number_format` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php that should help you further.

Comment: Is values saved with decimals in db

Comment: @NipunTharuksha no they are not

Comment: Use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) e.g. `echo number_format($row['ExpenseItem'], 2);`

Comment: @Nick That worked perfectly, using echo number_format($row['ExpenseICost'], 2); Thank you!

Comment: @sierra no worries.